# Harbor Breeze Lighting Issue

Tags: electrical

[image][image]

The part in question is on the right side of the top picture next to the white wires.

I have a Harbor Breeze ceiling fan/light combination that has been installed and working properly for over 5 years. Recently the lights quit working and after smelling melting plastic I cut the power and took it apart. I found this part (pictured) that showed signs of melting of the outer casing. It is next to the pull chain switch and it has two blue wires connected to it. It is approx 2 inches x 1.5 inches. Can you tell me what part name it is and what would cause it to get hot enough to melt and whether there might be another issue leading up to the heat issue. And also, is there a replacement part for this without buying a whole new lighting kit? I feel fortunate that I was able to find the problem before it led to an electrical fire. Inquiring minds need to know......Thanks, Mike Orlandini

Comment: What is this part connected to? I can't see where the light blue wires go in the photo you posted...

Comment: a couple of photo's from different angles would help. Is it a wireless fan? Or has it a remote installed in the canopy?

Comment: One blue wire leads to the wiring harness, while the other leads to the pull chain lead. No it isn't a wireless fan, nor does it have a remote. I can't attach another photo to this thread. I would have to send you a separate message.

Comment: The part in question is on the right side of the top picture next to  the white wires.

Comment: any help with identifying this part with the two blue wires would be appreciated.

Comment: @diniman -- put links to any extra photos of this you have in a comment and we can edit them in :)